# hyperlink model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to hyperlink a model attribute that publishes a website address.  Right now, my view shows:

```
<%= text_item 'Website', advisor.firm.webaddr %>
```

An advisor belongs to a firm and the firm has a web address.  I'm simply trying create a hyperlink in my view, so that a user can click on this attribute and get connected to the website.  Such a simple question I know, but am having trouble finding a solution. Thank you.

```
module TextItemHelper 
  def text_item(name, *values, &block) 
    label_tag = content_tag(:span, name, class: 'text-item__label') 
    content = if block_given? 
        label_tag + content_tag(:span, class: 'text-item__value', &block) 
      else 
        values.reduce label_tag do |acc, value| 
          content = value.presence || 'Not available' acc + content_tag(:span, content, class: 'text-item__value') 
        end 
      end 
    content_tag :span, class: 'text-item' do content 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: `text_item`? Where does this come from?

Comment: That comes from a helper that was created to sort text items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) tag:

```
<%= text_item 'Website', raw(link_to(advisor.firm.webaddr, advisor.firm.webaddr)) %>
```

Comment: thanks Tom!  I tried that and it works, but hyperlinks `Website` and not the model attribute.

Comment: It should display 'Website' on the screen and clicking the link should take you to the url contained in `advisor.firm.webaddr`. Is that what you want?  I am not sure what you mean by model attribute.  Which specific attribute?  Do you mean the name of the model?

Comment: @DCRubyHound: "but hyperlinks Website and not the model attribute" - it's not entirely clear what you mean by that, and what is it that you expect to happen. You should elaborate.

Comment: Do you want it to display 'Firm' instead of 'Website' in this case?

Comment: I think I know what you are doing...you want it to display 'Website: http://...' with a link.  Is that right?

Comment: yes @TomAranda you're correct!  I wanted to display what was published not the title.